# How can I resolve "___" is not defined when importing form into list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, ajax, json

My Code:

```
<script>
    $('#submitdata').click(function(){

    var itemProperties = {
        '__metadata': { "type": "SP.List" },
        "Title": FirstName  

    };

    $.ajax({
         url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ChangeOfAddressList')/items",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(itemProperties),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data.d));
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data.responseText);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I get "FirstName is not defined" in chrome debugger. Everything else seems to work as it does actually reach the list it just can't populate it with anything meaningful 
This is all triggered by a submit. The id of the input is "name"

Comment: Because you are treating FirstName as a function, do you mean "FirstName"?

Comment: Yep, You are right, however, instead of inputting the <input type="text" id="FirstName"/> it just put in the text "FirstName". Just need to figure that out and Illl go home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment response, you'd do it like:

```
var itemProperties = {
    '__metadata': { "type": "SP.List" },
    "Title": $("#FirstName").val();

};
```

Comment: Cheers, It worked except I just had to remove the ; at the end.